# Использование criteria из JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

В новом `Hibernate` использование `Criteria` является `Deprecated`. Как я могу заменить такой код с использованием `org.hibernate.Criteria`:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Role.class);
long id = ((Role) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name)).uniqueResult()).getId();
```

на его эквивалент с использованием `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder` из `JPA` ?

Comment: Эти все критерии такие ужасные, чтобы их набирать в ответах. Почитайте что ли этот сайт https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence. Есть pdf по этому сайту. Так и называется Java_Persistence.pdf. В интернете можно купить или спиратить книжки про jpa. Pro JPA 2 Mastering the Java Persistence API.

Comment: Я хотел написать простенький сервис для подготовки к собеседованию на джава джуниора. Вряд ли я на него попаду когда-нибудь, если по каждой технологии буду читать по книжке. И это в нерабочее время. :) Но за ссылку и название книги спасибо. Сохраню себе в будущее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`em` - экземпляр `EntityManager`.

```
public Long query(String name) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Role> cq = cb.createQuery(Role.class);
    Root<Role> root = cq.from(Role.class);
    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("name"), cb.parameter(String.class, "name")));
    // cq.distinct(true);
    Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
    q.setParameter("name", name);
    List<Role> result = q.getResultList();
    if (result.size() > 0) {
        return result.get(0).getId();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Ничего себе! В новом `hibernate` две строчки превратились в такой большой метод ?

Comment: Это обобщенная реализация, которая не зависит от Hibernate, а лишь использует абстракции JPA. Обычно никто не пишет под каждый запрос всю эту лапшу, а делают обертку и меняют лишь `cq.where`.

Comment: Только зачем distinct? uniqueResult()  соответствует getSingleResult(). try { return q.getSingleResult().getId() } catch (NoResultException) { return null; }

Comment: Да, согласен про unique, но ловить Exception все-таки дорого.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот когда есть что скопипастить (спасибо, Виктор)

```
public Long query(String name) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Role> cq = cb.createQuery(Role.class);
    Root<Role> root = cq.from(Role.class);
    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("name"), cb.parameter(String.class, "name")));
    try {
        // Тут возможно надо делать приведение типов, 
        // либо вызывать вариант метода, в котором указывается тип возвращаемого параметра
        // em.createQuery(cq, Role.class)...
        // либо и так сойдёт
        return em.createQuery(cq).setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult().getId();
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

или

```
public Long query(String name) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Role> cq = cb.createQuery(Role.class);
    Root<Role> root = cq.from(Role.class);
    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("name"), cb.parameter(String.class, "name")));
    List<Role> roles = em.createQuery(cq).setParameter("name", name).getResultList();
    return roles.isEmpty() ? null : roles.get(0).getId();
}
```

Ну то есть вариант Виктора без лишнего distinct и местами собранный в одну строку за счёт fluent-а, широко применяемого в JPA API.

Если используете генерацию статичной метамодели, тогда root.get("name") заменяется на root.get(Role_.name). Типа безопасно. Чо. Иначе на фига Вам вообще criteria, когда есть текстовый JPQL, а ещё лучше SQL?

Comment: SQL явно не лучше, если хотим абстрагироваться от синтаксиса БД. А для большинства приложений JPQL будет достаточно.

Comment: Ну это шутка. Хотя в каждой шутки есть доля истины, причём большая. Я например частенько применяю специфические запросы: полнотекстовы поиск, рекурсивные эти cte, которые в JPA вряд ли даже планировались и будут когда-либо. Да даже паршивый left join не сделать в JPA. А что касается абстракции от БД... Да кому она нужна на самом деле-то. Прямо эту базу меняют каждый день. Да и синтаксис в части покрываемой JPQL в общем оказывается у всех одинаковый.

Comment: Абстракция в том случае, когда требуется поддерживать несколько баз данных (да, такое бывает).

Comment: Бывает конечно. Сам видел китайское изделе на Delphi, где никакой абстракции в помине нет (BDE не в счёт, ибо даже китайцы с ней не связывались). Но работало же. И поддерживало все более-менее известные коммерческие базоводы. Ну китайцам конечно проще. Их миллиард. Один составляет запросы для Oracle, другой для DB2, и т.д. для MSSQL, для Sybase. Остальные их исполняют.